# A question about the application of but

Tags: meaning

I want to know what is the meaning of "but" in this combination: "thought of as but" like in the following sentence:
"Conscious thinking
and actions might be thought of as but the
outward manifestations of that whole person".

Comment: I think you could think of the "but" as "nothing but."

Comment: Thanks, but I think we should consider it as"something except"
Am I right?  Are the two interpretations the same? It seems they are contradictory.

Comment: 'But' in this context means 'only'.